# How can i only get hours minutes and second c#

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch

Hello guys i have a code that when i clicked the button, the button text changes into a chronometer but it appears miliseconds and when i try to remove it gives me error. Any help i would apreciate. The code was from something that i saw on web but i cant adapt it.

```
public partial class menu : Form
{
    Stopwatch cronometro = new Stopwatch();

    public menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(@"C:\MoldArtGestaoHoras\terminal.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs2);
        Dados.terminal = reader.ReadToEnd();
        terminal.Text = Dados.terminal;
        estado.Text = "";
        data.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        hora.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
        reader.Close();
    }

    private void setupbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //zerar o cronometro
        cronometro.Reset();
        timer1.Start();
        //iniciar o cronometro
        cronometro.Start();

    }

    private void avariabt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pausabt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void produzirbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void sairbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setupbt.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}", cronometro.Elapsed.Hours, cronometro.Elapsed.Minutes, cronometro.Elapsed.Seconds, cronometro.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Just try removing the `:{3:00}` and `, cronometro.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10`

Comment: String.Format() methods first parameter determines the placeholders and data formats of values. So when you remove `cronometro.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10` you also need to remove its placeholder: `"{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}"` should be `"{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}"`